# How to get keys and their value from a multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, key

I am trying to find how many instances a key shows up for and then I am trying to obtain their values as well.

Let's say I was the count how many times the key `tpoint` shows up in `packageContents`. Then I am trying to get a comma separated list of the `touches` from each `tpoint`. Something like this:

tpInstance = 2;

[tpoint = 21, tpoint = 9]

Does anyone know how I can obtain this?

```
var packageContents = {
        'packages': {
            'package': {
                'price': '32',
                'name': 'Gold Bundle Package',
                'calendar': {
                    'type': '2year',
                    'color': 'Brushed Nickel',
                },
                'tpoint': {
                    'type': 'Gold',
                    'touches': '21',
                    'years': '7',
                }
            },
            'package': {
                'price': '23',
                'name': 'Bronze Bundle Package',
                'calendar': {
                    'type': '2year',
                    'color': 'Brushed Nickel',
                },
                'tpoint': {
                    'type': 'Bronze',
                    'touches': '9',
                    'years': '7',
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var tpInstance = Object.keys(package).length;
    console.log(tpInstance);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change your `packageContents` structure to:

```
var packageContents = {
    'packages': [
        {
            'price': '32',
            'name': 'Gold Bundle Package',
            'calendar': {
                'type': '2year',
                'color': 'Brushed Nickel',
            },
            'tpoint': {
                'type': 'Gold',
                'touches': '21',
                'years': '7',
            }
        },
        {
            'price': '23',
            'name': 'Bronze Bundle Package',
            'calendar': {
                'type': '2year',
                'color': 'Brushed Nickel',
            },
            'tpoint': {
                'type': 'Bronze',
                'touches': '9',
                'years': '7',
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

this is because you have repeated keys named `package`.. and this will make the work:

```
var tpInstance = 0;
var result = [];
packageContents.packages.map(function(pack) {
    if('tpoint' in pack) {
        if('touches' in pack.tpoint) {
            result.push(pack.tpoint.touches);
            tpInstance ++;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So a few things here. In Javascript, object properties need to be unique. By setting `packageContents.packages.package` equal to the `Gold Bundle Package` and then setting the same property to the `Bronze Bundle Package` you effectively overwrite the original property. Like the other answer says, you can rewrite your object like so:

```
var packageContents = {
    'packages': {
        'package1': {
            'price': '23',
            'name': 'Bronze Bundle Package',
            'calendar': {
                'type': '2year',
                'color': 'Brushed Nickel',
            },
            'tpoint': {
                'type': 'Bronze',
                'touches': '9',
                'years': '7',
            }
        },
        'package2': {
            'price': '32',
            'name': 'Gold Bundle Package',
            'calendar': {
                'type': '2year',
                'color': 'Brushed Nickel',
            },
            'tpoint': {
                'type': 'Gold',
                'touches': '21',
                'years': '7',
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Note the keys are now *package**#***. My approach is gross, but it works. We can use `Object.keys()` to figure out the structure of the object and iterate over its values. This is my approach:

```
// The number of tPoitn objects found
var total_tPoints = 0;

// The values of the "touches" value within the tPoint objects
var tPoint_touches = [];

// Returns an array of the keys of "package" === ["package", "package1"]
var packageContentKeys = Object.keys(  packageContents[  Object.keys(packageContents)[0]  ]  );

// Loop through that array
for (var i = 0; i < packageContentKeys.length; i++) {

    // Get the individual "package#" object
    //                        base object               "packages"                   "package1", "package2", etc
    var individual_package = packageContents[  Object.keys(packageContents)[0]  ]   [  packageContentKeys[i]  ];

    // Get the tPoint object
    var individual_tPoint = individual_package.tpoint;

    // If it exists, then we do stuff
    if (individual_tPoint !== undefined) {

        // Increment the total number of tPoint objects
        total_tPoints++;

        // Push a string with the value of the touches value
        tPoint_touches.push("tPoint" + " = " + individual_tPoint.touches);
    }

}

// Print the stuff
console.log("Total tPoints: " + total_tPoints);
console.log("tPoint Array:  [" + tPoint_touches + "]");
```

Hopefully the comments clear up any confusion.